# Font awesome not working on root domain

Tags: fonts, font-awesome

I have an issue with font awesome on a website. I when acces the website aka www.website.com the font is not working and when i access it aka www.website.com/index.php is working fine. Can you guys help me with this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Does each page have the same header.php file? I've never had this problem before but sounds like it could just be a path issue.

Can you post the header.php or the code in the  section?

Comment: I guess so.. it's an opencart site. sure i can post the code here from the theme.. How can i post a bigger comment ? Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to just post up to 600 characters here I think. Post the code here and we'll see if there's anything strange.

Comment: Here is a pastebin of header.tpl http://pastebin.com/tBk9GiKX thanks for the help!